# Getting total values of combined attribute's value from two different table using SQL

Tags: sql-server, php

I want to get total values from combined two attributes named amount, using this query and display it in my HTML form,

```
$Withdraw = query("SELECT tbl_vehicle.carid,
tbl_vehicle.reg_num,
IFNULL(tbl_fuel.sum_amount,0) + 
IFNULL(tbl_maintenance.sum_amount,0)
AS amount
FROM tbl_vehicle tbl_vehicle
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT carid,
sum(trim(replace(amount, '$', ''))+0) sum_amount
FROM tbl_fuel
GROUP BY carid) tbl_fuel ON tbl_fuel.carid = tbl_vehicle.carid
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT carid,
sum(trim(replace(amount, '$', ''))+0) sum_amount
FROM tbl_maintenance
GROUP BY carid) tbl_maintenance
ON tbl_maintenance.carid = tbl_vehicle.carid
WHERE tbl_fuel.sum_amount
IS NOT NULL OR tbl_maintenance.sum_amount IS NOT NULL");
```

this is my HTML form.

```
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    <h3 align="center">Withdrawal Per Vehicle</h3>
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Plate Number</th>
                                <th>Amount</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php foreach($Withdraw as $w): ?>
                                <?= '<tr>' ?>
                                    <?= '<td>' . $w["carid"] . '</td>' ?>
                                    <?= '<td>' . $w["reg_num"] . '</td>' ?>
                                    <?= '<td>' . $w["amount"] . '</td>' ?>
                                <?= '</tr>' ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

I hope someone will tell me what exactly to do, or tell me the alternative way to combine all values from attribute named amount.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this issue. i used this script to get total in column.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var table = document.getElementById("expense_table"), sumVal=0;
    for(var i=1;i<table.rows.length;i++){
        sumVal=sumVal+ parseFloat(table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML);
    }
    console.log(sumVal);
    document.getElementById("val").innerHTML="Total Expenses: " + sumVal;
</script>
```

I hope someone will find this useful to their projects.